# Is it possible to create a completely new instance of the members of a parent class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python version 2.7.

**Scenario**

```
class A(object):
    x = 0

class B(A):
    pass

ai = A()
bi = B()

#Then:
id(ai.x) == id(bi.x)
>>> True
```

What I'd like to know is if there is a way, other than having all the class member definitions in `__init__` to have instances of `class B` have their own copies of `x` without having to redefine them in `class B`?
Perhaps some `type()` tricks?

Haven't found anything yet, but I'll keep looking, figured here would be the best place to find an answer.
Any insight is greatly appreciated.

**edit:** grammars

**edit2** To clarify as I didn't really use the best example.

```
class Y(object):
    def __init__(self):
         self.z = 0

class A(object):
    x = Y()

class B(A):
    pass

ai = A()
bi = B()

id(ai.x) == id(bi.x)
>>> True
ai.x.z = 3
id(ai.x) == id(bi.x)
>>> True
```

Now the issue occurs that as I don't reassign `x` in `class B` they both point to the same instance of `class Y` even if members of the instance of `class Y` change.

If you're familiar with Django I'm almost recreating how their Forms work. I didn't decide to go with a `metaclass` for the forms and then build up a dictionary of the fields everytime a new instance is created, perhaps I will need to switch to using a `metaclass`.

**edit the third** I'm realising now the impossibility I'm asking of the interpreter. As once I assign an instance of a class to a member there's no way for the inherited classes to know how to create a new instance of that class. Therefore for my problem it seems metaclasses are the only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, it doesn't matter with immutable objects.  `bi` references a new object if it is ever assigned.

```
class A(object):
    x = 0

class B(A):
    pass

ai = A()
bi = B()

print id(ai.x) == id(bi.x)
ai.x=3
print id(ai.x) == id(bi.x)
```

Result:

```
True
False
```

Note also, that even if you initialize `x` in `__init__`, that due to implementation-defined behavior, immutable objects can be cached and reused, and instances `ai` and `bi` still share the `0` object.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

class B(A):
    pass

ai = A()
bi = B()

print id(ai.x) == id(bi.x)
ai.x=3
print id(ai.x) == id(bi.x)
```

Result (with CPython 2.7.2):

```
True
False
```